# How to get (admin) access to a SP2010 Site

Tags: security

Someone managed to delete all the user permissions from a SP2010 (sub)Site, including their own (this person was the only site admin).

How do you give (the site owner or an administrator account) access to this 'locked out' site?

Answer (score 4):

You can manage the site collection administrators for each site collection in the central administration. A site collection administrator could then add the deleted users accounts and reset the permissions.